# how to get the event id of the particular event created in calander in android studio?

Tags: android, android-calendar

i use this code to insert the value in calander,using the for loop i am inserting multiple values in diffrent date,but i got stuck in this place.

```
   JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(L);
                year[L] = jsonObject.getString("year");
                month[L] = jsonObject.getString("month");
                day[L] = jsonObject.getString("day");
                StartTime[L] = jsonObject.getString("StartTime");
                Endtime[L] = jsonObject.getString("Endtime");
                Hours[L] = jsonObject.getString("Hours");
                final ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
                event.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
                event.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "WORKING SCHEDULE OF THE WEEK");
                event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "selva");
                event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "chennai");
```

after i added the events in calander i need to get the event id of that event created.

which means, if the for loop is executed for 5 times to insert the values in diffrent dates of calander,

1)when the for loop is executed for the first time ,it should insert the event and it should return the id of that particular event and it should store in array.

i used this code to retrive the id of the all the event added in the calander.

```
String event_ID = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events._ID));
```

but,i need to get only event id of events created by me,every time when the for loop is excuted for the particulr event added.

can anyone help to retrive the event id ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri ref=getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(baseUri, event)
```

Comment: s i am not inserting the _ID ,because i think it is unique id created by calander! is it right?

ok if i can do an auto increment ,how to do that! can you suggest any code for that?

Comment: Just place this 'AUTOINCREMENT'  right after the _ID when you create the database.

Comment: you are saying that i should insert the autoincrement id from the database to calendar EVENTS _ID?

Comment: the line  baseUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events"); is the end of the for loop,when the for loop is executed first data will be inserted and it should return the event id of Particular event created like wise till the for loop is finished

Comment: addd this  event.put(CalendarContract.Events._ID, startMillis); i think it will help

Comment: can you explain what it does? startmills

Comment: Insert will return you a URI that will contain all the information about that event

Comment: is it possible to add unique id by me in calander which should not be edited or deleted by the user?
i have a worker sheduling database in that each row of schedule has unique id,is it possible to store that id in calander,which should not be edited or deleted by the user!is it possible to do like that?

Comment: Uri ref=getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(baseUri, event);

Use it like this
ref will contain all info about your inserted event

Comment: sir i tried that too,i able to get all the information,like id,desc,title,etc.of all the event created in that calander,there is no use of getting all the id,desc,etc,but what i need is when i executed the for loop it should return the event id of that particular event created in that event, which event created by me.

Comment: Sir, you are inserting in a loop, so when you insert you'll get a URI & you have to save that

Comment: ok sir ,i got an idea to do that,i will try in that way!sir did you see my question "is it possible to add unique id by me in calander which should not be edited or deleted by the user? i have a worker sheduling database in that each row of schedule ......"is it correct idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164307/discussion-between-warlock-and-selva-surya).